# Static Routes and selection

Tags: routing

For what I know, Static Routes don't have a Metric. So, what if a Router has more than one Static Route to a Network?

Let's say that on the topology below we have Static Routes configured, and **R1** can reach **R3** both via `192.168.13.3` and via `192.168.12.2` .

Let's also say that the bandwidths on the links are:

```
10Mbps  on 192.168.13.0/24
100Mbps on 192.168.12.0/24
100Mbps on 192.168.23.0/24
```

Which path will be chosen by the Packets from **R1** to **R3**?

[image]

Comment: If you configure more than one static route to the same destination, and the routes have different next-hop gateways but have the same metrics and administrative distance, the Layer 3 device load balances among the routes using basic round-robin.

Comment: @Cown surely it's going to be dependent on the OS, as there are several perfectly sensible alternative behaviours.

Comment: @jonathanjo yes i was referring to Cisco IOS, sorry.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the router's operating system, as it could do any of several perfectly sensible alternatives.

As Cown says in the comments, for Cisco IOS:

> If you configure more than one static route to the same destination, and the routes have different next-hop gateways but have the same metrics and administrative distance, the Layer 3 device load balances among the routes using basic round-robin.

Answer (score 0):

When two or more static routes are configured to same destination in router with same AD value  . Router will load balance traffic on available static route  configured links by round -robin method.

We have feasibility to divert traffic or control traffic on two static routes by changing administrative value (AD). Default AD value for static route  is 1.